# OAuthException: redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, openid, facebook-social-plugins

This is the error which I'm getting when I'm trying to login using facebook OpenId. I'm trying it on local machine. what should be redirect-uri and where we need to set that uri?I have given redirect_uri as LoginSuccess.xhtml page. Any help will be great full. Thank You

```
    {
    "error": {
    "message": "redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 191
             }
    }
```

Comment: You mean, you don't understand what exactly the term "absolute URI" means? Have you tried looking up that term in Google or Wikipedia? Have you tried looking up "RFC 3986"?

Answer (score 0):

There error states what the issue is. Instead of passing `LoginSuccess.xhtml` use `http://my.domain.tld/myapp/LoginSuccess.xhtml` but then exactely as it should be

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=431479790351471&response_type=code&redirect_uri=%2Fdomain.in%2Fxhtml%2FmyApp%2FLoginSuccess.faces&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location,offline_access        Error is coming here. I'm trying on locahost.So when I give http://localhost:8080 before domain it works for me.